# How to include the name in the to: address of the person you are sending mail to in mailx(UNIX-HP)

Tags: mailx

I am trying to use the `mailx` program to send an e-mail.

I want the name of the person to be included in the **toaddress@domain.com**  like the normal one on Microsoft Outlook or gmail account e.g `"Thomas<tmuller@gmail.com>"`

```
ls -l $HOME | mailx -r "fromaddress@domain.com" -s "The content of my home directory"    toaddress@domain.com
```

Comment: I assume the `mails` in your example was a typo, if not please roll back.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the `"Thomas<tmuller@gmail.com>"` when you use `sendmail` directly. That is not so complicated, you just need to create the header

```
From: fromaddress@domain.com
To: Thomas <tmuller@gmail.com>
Subject: The content of my home directory

<output from ls>
```

There has to be an empty line between the header and the content. You can achieve this with:

```
(echo -e 'From: fromaddress@domain.com\nTo: Thomas <tmuller@gmail.com>Subject: The content of my home directory\n\n' ls -l $HOME | sendmail -t
```

However, please note, that e.g. in Thunderbird, if the recipient has a name for `tmuller@gmail.com` in the addressbook, then that name will be displayed, instead of `Thomas`

Comment: for UNIX-HP mailx does not have the -t option like the sendmail utility. the -r for UNIX is for the from address

Comment: @Mree Then just try with the double quoted text: `-r "Thomas <tmuller@gmail.com>"`

Comment: I have tried it, it only comes with e-mail address only

Comment: @mree Ok, but that is the case on Linux as well. If you want the recipient to see the name you put there, it has to be in the mail header and then you cannot use mailx. I will update my answer for an alternative.